# I don't think I get Prolog's recursion

Tags: prolog

foo/3 is a predicate that does something with two lists and outputs another one.

```
foo([], Ys, Zs) :-
    append(Zs, Ys, Final),
    write(Final),
    % ?

foo([X|Xs], Ys, Zs) :-
    stuff(X, Ys, NewYs, NewZs),
    foo(Xs, NewYs, NewZs).
```

I want the Final to be the L in the top-level call like foo([1,2,3], [a,b,c], L). I looked at the trace, it seems I am doing something backwards;

```
    ...
    Exit: (9) write([c]) ? 
    Exit: (8) foo([], [], [c]) ? 
    Exit: (7) foo([c], [], []) ? 
L = [].
```

Comment: If you describe more specifically *what* you want to do, this question may be a lot easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by changing `foo([], Ys, Zs)` to `foo([], Ys, Final)`.

However, what are you trying to do?  The reason you're getting `L=[]` is because Prolog has satisfied your base case (`foo([], Ys, Zs)`) with the empty list.